# Temporarily disable drag pan of map

Tags: openlayers-2

I want to disable an OpenLayer map's draw pan during activation of a DrawFeature Control. What I am trying to do so far, is overwriting the dragstart method of `OpenLayers.Handler.Drag.prototype` in the control's `activate` method and readjusting it in its `deactivate` method.

However, I am not happy with this since I would prefer to tinker around with the Drag Handler object directly - instead of its prototype - and besides, I am pretty sure there is a more elegant solution which I was not able to find so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could deactivate/activate the control.  It's usually created automatically as part of the default navigation control, so locate the control containing a dragPan object and call the appropriate method on that (deactivating the entire navigation control is also possible but would also prevent mouse or touch zoom).

```
map.controls.forEach(function(control) {
  if (control.dragPan) {
     control.dragPan.deactivate();
  }
});



map.controls.forEach(function(control) {
  if (control.dragPan) {
     control.dragPan.activate();
  }
});
```